# MATLAB kill system command

Tags: matlab

I run a system command in MATLAB which is a solving algorithm. I don't want to wait as long as it will get to the end (because it takes hours). I just need the system answers from the 1. minute of the system command.
Is there a way to kill the prozess after that from MATLAB?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ctrl-C will stop all the program. Not just the system command.

Comment: which operating system?

Comment: Windows 7 with Matlab 2010

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60101154/how-to-know-elapsed-time-during-execution-of-system-command-in-matlab/60104407#60104407

Answer (score 1):

### Windows

`Ctrl-C` at the MATLAB's console.

### Unix-like

Type at the terminal:

```
kill -2 $matlab_pid
```

You can find MATLAB's pid by running:

```
ps -aux | less
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to do so.
In the command window, just hold Ctrl key and then press C to terminate current MATLAB process.

Answer (score 0):

**Ctrl + C** in the MATLAB command window

If you are running MATLAB from Ubuntu (probably OSX as well), you can open the terminal window you're running it from and close it directly, or *Ctrl + C at the terminal as well*.

Comment: OK. The problem is that I use this external system command in a function which is in a GUI. If I hit Ctrl+C the whole GUI stops. I just want to kill this dos command.